# Autofac, override all registration within a scope

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, scope, autofac

I have a container that is build with multiples instances of `T`.
I resolve them like this :

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifeTimeScope())
{
    var allMyTs = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<T>>();
}
```

It works great.
However within a specific scope, in some cases, I want to be able to override all of T with a specific instance. I already know that there's a override of BeginLifeTimeScope that can have a `Action<ContainerBuilder>`for this specific registration.

So I tried

```
var specificT = new T();
using(var scope = container.BeginLifeTimeScope(a => {
    a.RegisterInstance(T).AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces();
    a.RegisterInstance(new List<T>{ specificT }).As<IEnumerable<T>>();
}))
{
    var allMyTs = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<T>>();
}
```

In this case, I expect that allMyTs only contains specificT, but it's not, I get all my registered T and the specific one also.
Is anyone have an idea or ever implemented this ?

Comment: You shouldn't be registering things inside a lifetime scope like that. Give http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html a squiz - I suspect you want to use `ResolveNamed`.

Comment: I've seen this is the only proper way to add registration within a specific context, because Update method of Container is deprecated and not recommended...

Comment: What did you think of the link I provided? `but it's not.` You've told us what it **isn't** doing? Can you tell us what it **is** doing?

Comment: I updated my question. However, I don't see how registered a named instance can solve my problem, because I don't want to modify code within the scope. I over simplified example here, but it's far more complex that this. The main issue is to be able to override all the instances of a type with a specific one

Comment: Can you talk us through why you are using Service Locator (i.e. calls to `.Resolve` rather than constructor injection)? Could you possibly show some some less simplified code?

Comment: The question remains the same if I inject IEnumerable<T> in ctor of a class, I still want to override within a scope all instance with a specific one.

Comment: I would suggest to register your Ts in the autofac module with code similar to log4net autofac module. The trick/bug/feature is that such registration is not inherited by child scope - so u must overwrite/repeat it on each child scope.